# vtiger cron sorry! attempt to access restricted file

Tags: cron, cron-task, vtiger

I'm trying to run `vtigercron.sh` file, but i have error

```
Sorry! Attempt to access restricted file.
```

I tried to do everything as described here but it didn’t help me

https://www.vtexperts.com/sorry-attempt-to-access-restricted-file/
[Vtiger Custom Module : "Sorry! Attempt to access restricted file."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060930/vtiger-custom-module-sorry-attempt-to-access-restricted-file)
[Vtiger web service "sorry! attempt to access restricted file" response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138774/vtiger-web-service-sorry-attempt-to-access-restricted-file-response)

As far as I understand, this problem appeared after deleting and creating a user
please help me, what else could be the problem?

Comment: what is the result of `ls -l vtigercron.sh`

Comment: -rwxrwxrwx 1 ooduser psacln 651 Dec  8 12:50 vtigercron.sh

Comment: which user did you delete? this error usually shows when the crm is trying to access a file which is not present - invalid file name etc. you can debug by changing the code in include/utils/CommonUtils.php - search for the error string and try printing the file name it is trying when it fails. let me know your results

Comment: i don't have this error on this direcotry and file. But I got to the point that the file is being returned to me Sorry! Attempt to access restricted file modules//.php, but it does not exist at all in the system vtiger

Comment: pinaki, can you help me?

Comment: check the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62801383/vtiger-cron-jobs-not-triggering-workflows-how-can-i-troubleshoot