# vTiger cron jobs not triggering workflows. How can I troubleshoot?

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

I'm running a Vtiger instance on a cloud server.

All was well until about two weeks ago when the workflows stopped sending.

I have verified that the cron jobs are executing. However, this is a shared hosting environment so as far as I know I don't have access to the cron logs.

I have checked that the Bash script that triggers the job has the right permissions. And yet, it is still not runnig.

Does anybody have experience with vTiger and has successfully troubleshooted this? Judging by the vTiger community forums this seems to be a recurrent problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this issue by modify vtigercron.php. check the follwoing link and replace that with current file.

https://gist.github.com/hamidrabiei/2dc80e603b8f9cf28c9639f314dd74e6

after replacement you can run workflows via wget command and set new cronjob

```
*/5 * * * * wget --spider "http://yourvtigerurl.com/vtigercron.php" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

try running the php script from the command line. Just go to your vtiger directory and then run `php -f vtigercron.php` and see what the output is.

Sometimes shared hosting companies change php versions without notifying its users. It can be the case that the php for cli (command line) was changed and that the `vtigercron.php` script doesn't work for that particular version of php.